# Solr fullname search

Tags: solr

I'm trying to set up a fullname search in Solr. Until now I thought my work was fine until I've found something strange, and I can't figure out how to correct it.

So I want to be able to do searches on fullnames. My index is a database where I get first name and last name and put them in one multivalued field with keyword tokenizer.

Here's my fieldtype :

```
<fieldType name="text_auto" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Everything works fine, I can search only a first name OR lastname and it gives me the full names that exists, and it also works for full names in any order if there's no mispelling.

I just noticed something wrong ! For example, if I ask for Dupont dupont, it'll give me every Dupont that exists, even the ones for which the first name doesn't match with dupont. I guess it's because dup is found a second time in the fullname... The problem is that if they're looking for "dupont d", they'll find every Dupont that exist because "d" is contained in Dupont ! That's not what I want, I want to find every Dupont with a d in their first name (the other string).

So I need to find a way to make it work, I tried many different tokenizers and filters but I'm affraid it's not possible...
Thank you for any help you could provide me !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are searching with something like:

```
q=dupont d
```

Which will have no problem with finding the terms in any order, or even as the same term in the index, in the case of `dupont dupont` (I'm assuming, by the way, that you are setting the default operator to `AND`, since this sort of behavior is surprising).  If you want to find the phrase "dupont d" in that order, you should search with a quoted phrase query:

```
q="dupont d"
```

or for `dupont dupont`

```
q="dupont dupont"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For now I'm using SolrJ to query my Solr server. The best way to get the responses I want for now is to take my query and process it in Java before querying Solr. I take every word separated by spaces and put an "*" before and after, and put a "AND" between them. That's working fine except for my problem. I'm trying to make it work with double quotes (I already tried) but it doesn't seem to work, I'll try defining the q.op in my configuration because I didn't !

Comment: Well I've got no results when I try to use double quotes and multiples word separated with spaces. It works with double quotes if there"s only one word in the search.

Comment: I think the better solution would be to rely on Lucene to provide highing scoring to the documents that match in more terms (ie. while "dupont AND d" matches "dupont h" and "dupont d", that latter recieves a higher score). If you must support searching for wildcards in queries, you will need a query parser that supports it (particularly [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html)).  Also, I recommend against leading wildcards, if you can possibly avoid them, in the interest of performance.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's hard to find precise information on Solr ! I'll delete my first wildcard, I don't really need it to be honest. My problem with the score is that I must have an alphabetical order in the end, I guess Solr is fine for my suggester, but it's not the best solution for my result list... I'll try to use the complexPhraseQueryParser, but I don't have much time to try it today (and on holiday tonight !).

Comment: Have you tried sorting on score first, and alphabetically second (like `new Sort(Sort.RELEVANCE, new SortField("text", SortField.Type.STRING));`)?  I find this works very well with simple searches, where many results may have equal relevance.